# jscs : Expected end of node list but "CommentBlock" found

Tags: reactjs, jscs

JSCS is not able to parse my ReactJS Component. 
It errors in the first line of the page with the error "Expected end of node list but "CommentBlock" found" :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error was because I had commented out a line of JSX in my reactJs component.

```
<Nav pullRight>
    {/*/<li><Link to='/auth/login' activeClassName='route--active'>login</Link></li>*/}
</Nav>
```

Removing the inline comment fixed the issue.